# How can I suspend default shortcut menu and substitute with a custom menu in the TOC?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, vb.net

I looking for solution **(using ArcObject SDK 10.1 (VB.NET) ArcMap Addin template)** to substitute the default shortcut "right-click" menu in the TOC (When a TOC Item is right-clicked) with a custom menu when a custom tool is active.  (I would like default functionality when a custom tool is inactive)

I already do that in the map - I have a custom tool and when the tool I show a custom menu on right-click.  The custom behavior only works within the map frame.

How can I do the same in the TOC?

[image]

Comment: The question in your post "how can i gather information about the TOC item that was right-clicked or left-clicked in the TOC" doesn't really match the question in the title.  Anyway, did you try IMxDocument.SelectedItem?

Comment: Thanks @KirkKuykendall. Edited the post.  I want to focus on substituting the shortcut menu when a layer in the TOC is right-clicked.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there is no event exposed in ArcObjects for when a context menu is opened in the TOC, and no entry point to override it.

You would likely have to delve into the [Windows API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API), listen for specific messages and respond to whichever one corresponds to the default context menu display and replace it with your own. This can get really ugly so hopefully there is a better way.

There is some good info in these questions:

- [Event raised when selected layer changes in TOC](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/3685/753)
- [Disabling/overriding internal arcmap commands with vba](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/6203/753)
- [Performing action upon refresh command in TOC using ArcObjects?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/52695/753)

It may be possible to use [`ICustomizationFilter`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/0023/0023000000n6000000.htm) to listen for and block the context menu event but I have not tried it. This [blog post](http://rzeckoskiengineering.blogspot.com/2012/06/capturing-button-clicks-in-arcobjects.html) shows how something similar can be done within a VB.NET add-in. I am not sure how you would replace the context menu with your own though.